# Only link is visible while integrating twitter feed in a website?

Tags: twitter, web, integration

Here is the code i used given by the Twitter developer widget

```
 <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/PineappleTimes" data-widget- 
        id="274533936351289345">Tweets by @PineappleTimes</a>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s) 
 [0];if(!d.getElementById(id))
{js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer atlast. While previewing the code in dreamweaver the tweets won't be visible, only a link will be visible, but after uploding the code into server, it worked.